# Custom header not available while doing CORS

Tags: angularjs

I made some ajax GET call (`$http.get`) where server returns custom header in response. When I look into network the custom header (*x-filename*) is there, but when I try to access it via `response.header()` it's not there. Do you have any idea why my custom header is not in headers object?

[image]

Comment: Possibly, you are recieving a filtered response through the HTTP interceptor. Did you console the response object. What does it look like?

Comment: It looks like these header is not returned by `getAllAllResponseHeaders()`

Comment: The reason why it didn't work was lack of `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` in CORS configuration